# Google adsense show blank ads

Tags: adsense

The ads used to show properly but recently I noticed that the ads are blank. The iframe code is inserted but inside it's body there's nothing.

This is the code I'm inserting on the right column here for example https://www.countrypick.com/countries/united-kingdom:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:block"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-483193165XXXXX"
             data-ad-slot="2992948594"
             data-ad-format="auto"
             data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
```

Comment: I noticed the same. Many people are reporting it's adblock but I don't use one yet there's no ads for me as well. I only see weird mosaic placeholder pattern